# Moving an item in IB without changing its hierarchical position

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I have a situation where I have two sibling UIViews, one is a UIScrollView that fills the entire screen, and another is a much smaller UIView that sits above it.  Whenever I try to move the smaller UIView over the UIScrollView, IB wants to move it inside the UIScrollView.

How can I move the UIView without putting it inside the UIScrollView and maintain the sibling relationship?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use the inspector area on the right-hand side of the screen to manually adjust the x and y values. 
[image: manually adjust x and y in IB/Xcode]

Comment: I already knew that but I was hoping to be able to do via the usual interface.  But +1 for the answer anyway (I wish I could give +2 for the diagram).

Comment: For curiosity, I just tried with *all kinds* of keyboard modifiers while I dragged... no luck :-/

Comment: Yeah me too. And there are lots of shift combinations on the Mac :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use the keyboard arrow keys after selecting your object.